# How to add assemblies and compiled views from one ASP.NET MVC app into another at deploy time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, msbuild

We have a core Razor/MVC .NET application which we use TFBuild 2015 XAML build templates to compile the Razor views into assemblies. We are developing a customer-focused "add-on" Razor/MVC .NET application to the core application and expect multiple "add-ons" in the future. Our architecture relies heavily on dependency injection through Castle Windsor.

We are trying to extend the core MVC web site project at deploy/packaging time using ‘drop-in’ assemblies and views from the "add-on" MVC web site project that can be dropped in at deploy/packaging time.  The custom views (from the "add-on" MVC web project) must also be compiled along with the core website views at deploy time. We would expect to use dependency injection but we are open to any techniques that have been used successfully